# Mathematics of dewarping a reflection in a generalized cylinder

Tags: geometry, reference-request, symmetry

Because this question involves physics, I've posted a closely related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/613796/optics-and-mathematics-of-dewarping-a-reflection-in-a-generalized-cylinder).

---

Before I go to the effort of deriving all the equations, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a reference paper for dewarping an image in a generalized cylinder, such as this (Scott Fraser's *Reflections*):

[image: Scott Fraser's Reflections]

By "dewarping" of course I mean rectifying the reflected image:  un-distorting it so it appears as if viewed directly from the location of the curved mirror.

We can make some simplifying assumptions:  That the viewer (artist) is far from the mirror, that the mirror is cylindrically symmetric about its (vertical) axis, and that we can see the outer boundary (occluding contour) and hence know the radius as a function of height, $r(h)$.  The dewarping is a fairly straightforward (yet tedious) exercise in geometry.

I'm seeking a reference paper for two reasons:  1) I don't want to have to "re-invent the wheel," and 2) I want to cite and give proper acknowledgement to anyone who has solved this problem.

There's no need to point out the simplest version of this problem, where the mirror is a *cylinder* of constant radius.  I'm extremely familiar with the literature on cylindrical anamorphic art (and have published in it myself).

Of course, if anyone wants to work on this dewarping problem... great!

Comment: No idea, but maybe you should explain what dewarping means (presumably, reconstructing the image as seeing in a flat mirror). Also, consider trying Mathoverflow (site for research math, which includes applied  math) if nobody answers here.

Comment: This is not "research-level math" (MathOverflow), but I *did* put in on Physics.SE, as many there will know optics.

Comment: It depends: As long as you can make it precise, in my mind it counts as research level applied math. But, my guess is that you will have a better chance at PSE than here, at MSE, with this question. Good luck!

Comment: I can make the math as precise as necessary—that surely isn't the problem.  I'm certain that this problem could have been (and possibly was) solved in the 17th century, and didn't push any research-level math.  I'll wait a day or two to see if any answers come in, but I suspect at the end of the day I'll have to derive all the equations myself.

Comment: Since a post on [physics.se] was mentioned, it might be useful to include a link: [Optics and mathematics of dewarping a reflection in a generalized cylinder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613796). (Perhaps it would be a bit better to include it directly into both posts.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak:  Good idea.

Comment: I feel like this is much more a math question than a physics question, myself. The one thing that I'll suggest (and unfortunately I don't have good references to hand) is to check the computer graphics literature from the early 90s; this is very closely tied to ray tracing and reflection mapping, and in particular the latter phrase may unlock some info if you want to chase references.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki:  Thanks, yes, I've looked through the computer graphics literature and the closest I found was dewarping of (non-reflective) images of objects in the shape of generalized cylinders, such as a hotel with a curvy facade.  I've also checked the optics literature, including *American Journal of Physics*.  I also wrote a paper with a CS professor at Stanford who dewarped images reflected in *generalized* mirrors, but that relied on assumptions about the objects being reflected.  All close... but no cigar.

Comment: I think you're also going to need more simplifying assumptions about the rest of the environment, incidentally; unlike the cylindrical case where the pencil is relatively homogeneous, in this case the assumption that the viewer is at infinity doesn't buy you all that much, as the Z variance of the reflected rays means that their pencil will change with distance from the mirrored object.

Comment: The assumption that objects are far compared to the radius of curvature of the mirror will suffice.  It suffices for the "pure" cylinder case,  and the convex spherical mirror case, and I've used such software to great effect.  (Appeared in *Scientific American*!)